# Problems Navigation Drawer, Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I wanted to make a side menu for my android application. To do this, in MainActivity, I changed the root layout element from ConstraintLayout to DrawerLayout, added my own toolbar, and then wrote the side menu code. But when I started testing the app on my phone, the elements of my start fragment(fragment_start) moved to the right.
I sat all day, but did not understand what was the mistake, where did I screw up?
And there are a couple of questions in connection with this: Why is the hamburger not displayed on the toolbar, although I added the code for this (`appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,binding.drawerLayout)`)?
How can I make the side menu open only in the fragment that I need, and not in the whole application?

My code:

activyty_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF3700B3"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="Отель"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fragment_admin"
        android:title="About" />
</menu>
```

fragment_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".start.StartFragment"
   >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editInputEmail"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editInputPassword"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editInputPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editInputPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_registr"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_registr"
        app:strokeColor="#5584E6"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_registr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:text="Registration"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editInputPassword"
        app:strokeColor="#5584E6"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.hotel2


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var appBarConfig: AppBarConfiguration



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        APP_ACTIVITY = this


        setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar(this))
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,binding.drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)


    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfig) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of result with you unexpected behavior?

Comment: Attached to answer

Comment: Better to attach link to screenshot and don't post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's worked perfect before adding drawer*. **Nope**, it doesn't.

**What with my layout?**

Currently, your views are not properly attached to constraints that lead to inconsistence behavior, such as jumping to the top left corner of the screen. You better check constraint layout [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) or [videos](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout). `android:layout_gravity="right"` in navigation view may crash the app, use `start` instead. Also, you can replace constraint with [linear layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), it simpler and fits to your view requirements.

**Where is my menu icon?**

Idk, some strange behavior occurs while working with `setSupportActionBar()`. But you can setup toolbar directly `toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)`.

**How to control drawer state?**

You can listen destination changes `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener()` and lock drawer in particular screens `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` and vise-verse.

FYI [material drawer guideline](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer), [nav components & ui](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here as shown on the phone]

[image: Here is how it should be]

The first screenshot is as shown on the phone
The second is how it should be

Comment: Khm, can you remove start margin from any view in `fragment_start.xml` and check?

Comment: Removed from top EditText, EditText shifted to left

Comment: Now it looks as expected?

Comment: No, the EditText just moved to the left to the bottom of the screen.
I understand that you can just change the margin_start and everything will be fine, just before I made the side menu it looked like it should.